# PHP find value in multidimensional / nested array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've trawled the site and the net and have tried various recursive functions etc to no avail, so I'm hoping someone here can point out where I'm going wrong :)

I have an array named `$meetingArray` with the following values;

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [Meet_ID] => 9313 
        [Meet_Name] => 456136 
        [Meet_CallInNumber] => 
        [Meet_AttendeeCode] => 
        [Meet_Password] => 
        [Meet_ScheduledDateTime] => 2011-07-18 16:00:00 
        [Meet_ModeratorCode] => 
        [Meet_RequireRegistration] => 0 
        [Meet_CurrentUsers] => 0 
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [Meet_ID] => 9314 
        [Meet_Name] => 456120 
        [Meet_CallInNumber] => 
        [Meet_AttendeeCode] => 
        [Meet_Password] => 
        [Meet_ScheduledDateTime] => 2011-07-18 16:00:00 
        [Meet_ModeratorCode] => 
        [Meet_RequireRegistration] => 0 
        [Meet_CurrentUsers] => 0 
    ) 
)
```

I also have a variable named `$meetID`.

I want to know if the value in `$meetID` appears in `[Meet_Name]` within the array and simply evaluate this true or false.

Any help very much appreciated before I shoot myself :)

Comment: Please format your print_r next time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
function multi_in_array($needle, $haystack, $key) {
    foreach ($haystack as $h) {
        if (array_key_exists($key, $h) && $h[$key]==$needle) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

if (multi_in_array($meetID, $meetingArray, 'Meet_Name')) {
    //...
}
```

I am unsure what you mean by

> $meetID appears in [Meet_Name]

but simply substitute the `$h[$key]==$needle` condition with something that meets your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Write a method something like this:

```
function valInArr($array, $field, $value) {
 foreach ($array as $id => $nestedArray) {
  if (strpos($value,$nestedArray[$field])) return $id;
  //if ($nestedArray[$field] === $value) return $id; // use this line if you want the values to be identical
 }
 return false;
}

$meetID = 1234;
$x = valInArr($array, "Meet_Name", $meetID);
if ($x) print_r($array[$x]);
```

This function will evaluate true if the record is found in the array and also enable you to quickly access the specific nested array matching that ID.

Answer (score 0):

For single-dimensional arrays you can use `array_search()`. This can be adapted for multi-dimensional arrays like so:

```
function array_search_recursive($needle, $haystack, $strict=false, $stack=array()) {
    $results = array();
    foreach($haystack as $key=>$value) {
        if(($strict && $needle === $value) || (!$strict && $needle == $value)) {
            $results[] = array_merge($stack, array($key));
        }

        if(is_array($value) && count($value) != 0) {
            $results = array_merge($results, array_search_recursive($needle, $value, $strict, array_merge($stack, array($key))));
        }
    }
    return($results);
}
```